# CommandParameter of MetroEventToCommand doesn't work with control(Windows universal 10)

Tags: c#, mvvm, win-universal-app

i want to bind an event using MetroEventToCommand library.
http://metroeventtocommand.codeplex.com/

It calls the method however it doesn't give the control as parameter. It's says it's null.

this is what i have.

```
 <ScrollViewer x:Name="test">
     <ListView/>
     <metroEventToCommand:EventToCommandManager.Collection>
            <metroEventToCommand:EventToCommand Command="{Binding RefreshCommand}" Event="ViewChanging" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=test, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
     </metroEventToCommand:EventToCommandManager.Collection>
  </ScrollViewer>

  public RelayCommand<ScrollViewer> RefreshCommand { get; set; }

  private void init()
  {
     RefreshCommand = new RelayCommand<ScrollViewer>(Refresh);
  }

  private void Refresh(ScrollViewer o)
  {
        if (o != null)
        {

        }
  }
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: I would try changing the RelayCommand to RelayCommand<object>... that should let it get passed and you can inspect what is actually coming through.  Null means it is either not passing anything, or it doesn't meet the type requirement.  Full disclosure, I have not used metroEventToCommand before.

Comment: already tried that, it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

OK... not quite an answer, but I can't put code in a comment.  I put together a quick app using MVVM Light and using the Interactivity library instead of metroToEventCommand.

I can pass it from hooking up an event handler (of course)

```
private void onViewChanging(object sender, ScrollViewerViewChangingEventArgs e)
    {
        vm.RefreshCommand.Execute(this.test);
    }
```

I can also get it to fire the command WITH the parameter using the Loaded event or PointerEntered event

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="test" >
            <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <Core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="PointerEntered">
                    <Core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding RefreshCommand, Mode=OneWay}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=test}"  />
                </Core:EventTriggerBehavior>
            </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <ListView x:Name="myList"/>
        </ScrollViewer>
```

However, the Interactivity dll throws an exception (Cannot add instance of type 'Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core.EventTriggerBehavior' to a collection of type 'Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity.BehaviorCollection'.) when trying to use the ViewChanging, ViewChanged, DirectManipulationCompleted, etc. events - whether a parameter is used or not.  ManipulationCompleted does not fire the command (I've seen hints that commands cannot be bound to routed events).

So, it would seem that the concept works - but only for certain event types.  I'm sorry that isn't a solution to your challenge, but hopefully it is some additional information to help your attempts.